# How can I set up a dynamic grid based on flex or grid

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, css-grid

I'm scratching my head on how to create this specific dynamic grid using CSS. I've been attempting it using CSS grid, but I'm curious if I should instead use Flexbox.

I'm attaching the desired adjustable layout below in a mock-up I created.

[image: Desired dynamic layout]

I'm attempting this in VueJS, and this is the code I have so far:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const gridStyle = computed(() => {
  const base = 'grid-auto-rows: minmax(0, 1fr); grid-auto-flow: column;'
  if (visibleItems.value.length === 1) {
    return 'grid-template-columns: 1fr; ' + base
  } else if (visibleItems.value.length === 3) {
    return 'grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr; ' + base
  } else {
    return 'grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr; ' + base
  }
})

const itemStyle = (item: iFrame, index: number) => {
  const remainingItems = visibleItems.value.length - 2

  if (index === 0 && !itemIsVisible(items.value[1])) {
    return 'grid-row: span 4; grid-column: span 2; height: 100vh;'
  } else if (index < 2 && items.value.indexOf(item) < 2) {
    return 'grid-row: span 4; height: 100vh;'
  } else if (remainingItems === 1) {
    if (index === 1) {
      return `grid-row: span 1; `
    }
    if (index === 2) {
      return `grid-row: span 3; `
    }
  } else {
    const rowsToSpan = Math.min(4, Math.floor(4 / Math.max(1, remainingItems)))
    return `grid-row: span ${rowsToSpan};`
  }
}
</script>

<div class="grid h-screen gap-0" :style="gridStyle">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in visibleItems"
      :key="item.id"
      class="h-full w-full"
      :style="itemStyle(item, index)"
    >
</div>
</div>
```

This code has gotten me most of the way, but there are minor visual issues when I have two, three, four, and five items I'd love to sort out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way of setting this up would be to use CSS grid-template-areas.

That way you have simple control of the layout for each number of items.

This snippet uses JS to find the number of items and CSS does the rest:

```html
<style>
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vmin;
    aspect-ratio: 16/ 9;
    gap: 1vw;
  }
  
  .grid.n1 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A';
  }
  
  .grid.n2 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A A A A B B';
  }
  
  .grid.n3 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A A A A B B' 'A A A A A C C' 'A A A A A C C' 'A A A A A C C';
  }
  
  .grid.n4 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A A B B C' 'A A A B B D' 'A A A B B D' 'A A A B B D';
  }
  
  .grid.n5 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A A B B C' 'A A A B B D' 'A A A B B E' 'A A A B B E';
  }
  
  .grid.n6 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A A B B C' 'A A A B B D' 'A A A B B E' 'A A A B B F';
  }
  
  .grid.n7 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A B B C C G' 'A A B B D D G' 'A A B B E E G' 'A A B B F F G';
  }
  
  .grid.n8 {
    grid-template-areas: 'A A B B C C G' 'A A B B D D H' 'A A B B E E H' 'A A B B F F H';
  }
  
  .grid>* {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: A;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: B;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: C;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: D;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(5) {
    grid-area: E;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(6) {
    grid-area: F;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(7) {
    grid-area: G;
  }
  
  .grid :nth-child(8) {
    grid-area: H;
  }
</style>
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
<script>
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  const n = document.querySelectorAll('.grid > *').length;
  grid.classList.add('n' + n);
</script>
```

Comment: Nice solution, as an alternative of using JS, you could combine `:has()` and `last-child`. You could replace `.grid.n1` with `.grid:has(:nth-child(1):last-child) {}` and so on.

Comment: Would be neat to do the whole thing in CSS. Problem at the moment is not all main browsers support :has.

Comment: Yes, you're right, we're getting close to the support of `:has()` but it isn't cross browser compatible yet.

Comment: This is really nice, thank you. How do you suggest I support this design infinitely? i.e. Everything after the first two columns eventually condenses down to four items, with the last item taking up the remaining vertical space.

Comment: I don’t think I quite understand. What would 9 items look like etc? Is it a complete repeat of the pattern?

Comment: Exactly. It would be a complete repeat of the pattern from 3 on. The first and second columns will always be single items, but additional columns will be up to 4 items.

Comment: So the number of columns would expand to the right - with no expansion in the vertical direction?

Comment: Correct. The only vertical logic is the 1-4 items, with the last item taking the remaining space. After the 4th item is placed in the column, the next new item will create a new column, taking the entire vertical space.